# is it beneficial to Integrate Magento in Joomla for SEO purpose

Tags: magento, joomla

I am in a process to set up a Magento store, I am thinking to integrate the store with Joomla to Improve SEO(Search Engine Optimization). There are few plugins/extensions which make this integration easier i.e. [Jfunsion](http://www.jfusion.org/), [Magebridge](https://www.yireo.com/software/joomla-extensions/magento-api) and Jmint.

However the second thought hits my mind that is it really beneficial to integrate? Since there will be a performance loss due to integration.

Comment: Your question is not very good for StackOverflow; you're asking for comments and personal opinions, which means there's no "correct" answer, which is not in the spirit of SO.

Comment: just updated if you think that matters. :)

Comment: it was a suggestion about how to write a good question on SO, so that you get good answers and your questions are not blocked. I don't get anything out of it, it was for your convenience.

Comment: thanks Francesco, I agree with you. sometimes you never know why the question is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people integrate WordPress, or Joomla.   This isn't to boost SEO on shop (e-commerce) pages, but rather to create content.  This content may be included on your e-commerce pages then depending on your strategy, requirements and the extension you choose to use moving forward.

Comment: I understand there might be other factors for Joomla integration, however as you can see i have ignored them completely in question statement, just to get focus on SEO.

Comment: I would say there is no benefit for onpage optimisation of Magento content.

Comment: it will be helpful if you can elaborate it in a bit depth. I mean why you think it is not worthy for SEO?

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about integrating Joomla and Magento to improve SEO on Magento, unless you assume that with Joomla it will be easier to create new content.

Usually you integrate Joomla because it has many extensions (i.e. forum, support ticketing, archive, and so on) while Magento - AFAIK - focus on the "store" features only.

Comment: It can be used for SEO, since both installation share the same domain, and web crawler do not care what is installed on the domain. It search for specific keywords etc, and update results based on probability.

Comment: Yes I think I know about that, but then probably I misunderstood your original question, so just forget my answer.